# Angular 9 npm 'bindings' requesting 'fs' module. cannot resolve

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to compile my angular project for several days now, without any success. The issue is related to `bindings` npm package not being able to find `fs` which I assume is a webpack issue within angular. I have found some sources on github and SO telling me to put the code block below in my package.json but that doesn't seem to do anything... when running ng serve I get the small error, and if it would be useful when I run `ng build` it generates this [error](https://hatebin.com/woesbtbnjn) into my console.

I have done multiple clean re-installs of my npm folder and even isolated the library for testing. The worst thing about it is that the library is able to build in an html document but not when served in angular. I again assume it has to do with webpack, the library itself is compiled using the tsc and browserify.

```
"browser": {
    "fs": "empty"
  }
```

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\tassc\Projects\Configurator\node_modules\bindings'
resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\tassc\Projects\Configurator\node_modules\bindings'
```

```
{
  "name": "configurator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "azure-devops-npm-auth",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.3",
    "@types/three": "^0.103.2",
    "@types/webgl2": "0.0.5",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.6",
    "patio-covering-models": "0.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.28",
    "azure-devops-npm-auth": "^1.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

UPDATE: On closer inspection the actual library (patio-covering-models) I am using does also not build with webpack outside of angular. Browserify does not complain. How would I get around this? I should also mention that due to company policy I am unable to share the package that is causing this...

Answer (score 0):

FS is not longer in use according to NPM https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs